# Change Boxplot Axis Labels

Tags: r, boxplot, axis-labels

I have a data frame `mdata` which has the columns `variable` and `value` that I am plotting on a BoxPlot in R. I am plotting log10(value) on the Y-axis & variables on the X-axis. I want to change the labels on the Y-axis such that it shows the original values and not the log10(value).

```
>mdata

   ID          variable value
  SJ5444_MAXGT   coding 17455
  SJ5426_MAXGT   coding 17961
  HR1383_MAXGT   coding 17579
  HR5522_MAXGT   coding 17797
 CH30041_MAXGT   coding 20099
  SJ5438_MAXGT   coding 17467
```

I want the Y-axis range to go from min(mdata$value) to max(mdata$value) with an interval of 10000. But I am unable to do so.

The following is my code:

```
boxplot(log10(as.numeric(value))~variable,data=mdata,yaxt="n",border="red",main="Boxplot: Seattle Seq Annotation")

axis(side=2,labels=seq(min(mdata$value),max(mdata$value),10000),cex.axis=0.65,tck=-0.02,at=seq(min(mdata$value),max(mdata$value),by=10000))
```

I have tried to figure out what is the problem here but its not obvious. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: side=2 create the Y-axis. And I would think that it would be avery bad idea to convert a data.frame to matrix when you have any text columns.

Comment: sorry I wanted to create Y-axis, I have edited the typo.

Comment: Take the `as.matrix` out, too.

Comment: You forgot to log the values in the `at=`. The way to have seen that quickly was just to use `axis(2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be that your boxplots are based on `log10` of `value`, whereas the axis you are drawing uses the original values.  There are two ways to fix this.  Either use `log10` to generate your axis ticks, or else use `log="y"` when you generate your boxplots to do the coordinate transformation.  Here is an illustration with some sample data:

```
set.seed(123)
x<-sample(100,1000,T)
var<-sample(letters[1:5],1000,T)
```

Choice number 1:

```
boxplot(log10(x) ~ var,yaxt="n")
axis(side=2,labels=round(10^(seq(log10(min(x)),log10(max(x)),len=5)),2),at=seq(log10(min(x)),log10(max(x)),len=5))
```

[image]

Choice number 2:

```
boxplot(x ~ var,yaxt="n",log="y")
axis(side=2,labels=seq(min(x),max(x),len=5),at=seq(min(x),max(x),len=5))
```

[image]

You can get the ticks to be spaced logarithmically or linearly with either method by specifying the `at` parameter appropriately, for example, this command will place evenly spaced tick marks on a plot generated with `log="y"`:

```
 axis(side=2,labels=round(exp(seq(log(min(x)),log(max(x)),len=5)),2),at=exp(seq(log(min(x)),log(max(x)),len=5)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (need more than one annotation, so decrease the interval):

```
axis(side=2,labels=seq(min(mdata$value), max(mdata$value),1000),
         at=log10(seq(min(mdata$value),max(mdata$value),by=1000)))
```